# Server log shows Visitors asking for "408" with blank referrers and user agents,

Tags: apache-2.2, log-files

I've created a website in a similar pattern to another website I already have, and hosted it on a similar server (only on a different IP).

I've noticed that about 70% of my visitors (of no certain pattern, though all of them seemed to be IE users) make requests(?) for a "408":

[image: LOG]

For example, I see a user with a certain IP enters my website, and start making GET requests for the .php, images, etc., all with details about size, referrer, user agent etc.

but then comes this weird line (from the same IP), of this 408 thing.
I have no clue what this is and never seen such thing in any of my logs.

Can anyone tell what's the meaning of this and how to handle this?

Comment: `408` looks more like a response code than a URL and the "status" is 0, which is suspicious. Can you paste some raw logs and the `LogFormat` line associated with them?

Comment: what's a `LogFormat`?

Comment: You'll find it in your httpd.conf http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#logformat It's better to see the actual log entries than a formatted report (which might be mixing the fields -- I think this is what @Ladadadada is getting at)